# JQuery mobile slideStop and input field issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling, slider, touch-event

I've a problem with JQuery Mobile slider. In my case user should be able to enter value from the slider input field as well as using the slider itself. However I don't want to use the "change" event to handle slide changes since there will be lot of those when moving the slider. I know this can be solved by using "slidestop" event but how to get event fired when user has entered the value to the input field ? When you enter number to it slider moves but it doesn't fire any events. Preferably I would both slide stop and change to be bound to the same handler.

So slide stop works ok:

```
$("#tempslider").on("slidestop", function(e) {
    $("#output").html($("#tempslider").val());
});
```

but on change triggers with every slide movement + enter key in the input field.

```
$("#tempslider").on("change", function(e) {
    $("#change").html($("#tempslider").val());
}
```

Here is a simple fiddle with slider with change event currently commented out: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nad6ecta/)

Comment: Welcome to SO http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Add relevant code please.

Comment: you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8hphL2jp/

Comment: Infact that could work. I meant more like triggering slidestop handler from the input field. I managed to get one kind of solution working like this as well:

`$("#tempslider").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#tempslider").trigger("slidestop");
    }
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a dead post, but the comment from @Janne finally helped me to figure this out, and I hope it helps even one person with the same issue.

```
let slider = $('#<sliderId>');

slider.on('change', function() {
   slider.trigger('slidestop');
});
```

It seems silly to me still that jQuery Mobile does not bind input change to the slidestop event (assuming a callback for only one or the other is supplied at initialization).